# python tkinter show images in a directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a folder which has some images. I want to display all the images using tkinter in a single window. Also whenever I click any image displayed in the window, I need to display the path of the image. I tried using for loop but it prints all the image file path. Here is the code I tried,

```
from Tkinter  import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def getFileName(image):
    print str(image)

gtk = Tk()
def showImages(folder):   
    for images in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if images.endswith("png"):
            im = Image.open(images)
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            imageButton = Button(gtk, image=tkimage, command=getFileName(images)
            imageButton.image=tkimage
            imageButton.pack()
gtk.mainloop()
```

Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us also the imports. Your code isn't runnable!

Comment: I have added the imports now.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? The following line "imageButton.image=tkimage" gives me an syntax error in Python 2.7.

Comment: I'm running python 2.7 and it doesn't show me any errors. All I get is the empty window.

Comment: How did you install `PIL`?

Comment: `sudo pip install pillow` this will provide `PIL`

Comment: I did the same. Which version of PIL are you using? Do a `pip list`. It should give you that info.

Comment: I'm using Pillow 3.4.2.

Comment: That's probably why I'm having this problem. I'm using Pillow (4.0.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for images in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if images.endswith("png"):
            im = Image.open(images)
            tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            handler = lambda img = images: getFileName(img)  #here modify
            imageButton = Button(gtk, image=tkimage, command=handler)#here
            imageButton.image=tkimage
            imageButton.pack()
```

> Because button-press callbacks are run with no arguments, if we
>   need to pass extra datato the handler, it must be wrapped in an object
>   that remembers that extra data and passes it along, by deferring the
>   call to the actual handler. Here, a button press runs the function
>   generated by the lambda, an indirect call layer that retains
>   information from the enclosing scope. The net effect is that the real
>   handler.
>     **-- << Programming Python>> page 435**

Comment: `RuntimeError: Too early to create image`